# Dependency problem between files using Visual 2019/CMake/Ninja

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, ninja

I have a problem of undetected dependencies in a project I'm creating with Visual 2019/CMake/ninja. For a demonstration of this problem I have created a small case with two classes ClassA and ClassB.

The .cpp file of ClassA is:

```
#include "ClassA.h"

#include "ClassB.h"

ClassA::ClassA()
{}


ClassA::~ClassA()
{}

void ClassA::callPrivateB()
{
    ClassB toto;
    toto.privateFct();
}
```

The .h file of ClassB is:

```
#pragma once

class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB();

    ~ClassB();

    void privateFct();
};
```

And the main.cpp is:

```
#include <ClassA.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ClassA toto;

    toto.callPrivateB();

    return 0;
}
```

Note: ClassA.h, ClassB.cpp, and CMakeLists.txt are not added too do not put to many code.

I'm compiling this application. Everything works well. That is normal. Now, I'm changing the file ClassB.h to put privateFct private. Then I request to recompile the application. And the result is:

```
ninja: no work to do.
Generate all: OK.
```

So, the fact that ClassA.cpp depends of ClassB.h has not been detected by ninja? cmake? Visual? 
Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: What the content of the CMake files looks like?

Comment: it is just the add_executable (Test main.cpp ClassA.h ClassA.cpp ClassB.h ClassB.cpp).

Comment: With a colleague with suspect now ninja. My computer is in French. His computer is in English. On my computer ninja -t deps answers "no dependency" for each file. On his computer the answer is correct. It might be related to the fact that ninja seems to have troubles to filter the messages "Note: include file:".

Comment: I'd report the issue to ninja. Visit [their issue tracker](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues) and describe the problem. They will be primarily interested in the CMake file and the generated Ninja build file.

Comment: Issue for ninja published.